# Add color to .obj in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, .obj

I am new to ThreeJS and have a simple question. I have the following code that will work properly, but I cannot add color to my .obj. The short and narrow of it is that I designed a game controller in Solidworks 2012, then I exported the CAD file as a .stl. I then used MeshLab to export the .stl as a .obj. Now I use the .obj in ThreeJS and it works, but I cannot for the life of me get color added to the .obj. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - vtk loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="" target="_blank">three.js</a> -
        vtk format loader test -
        model from <a href="" target="_blank">The GeorgiaTech Lagre Geometric Model Archive</a>,
        </div>

        <script src="three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>

        <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="BinaryLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var container, stats;

            var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

            var cross;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10 );
                camera.position.z = 200;
                camera.position.y = 200;

                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

                controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
                controls.panSpeed = 2;

                controls.noZoom = false;
                controls.noPan = false;

                controls.staticMoving = true;
                controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                scene.add( camera );

                // light

                var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                dirLight.position.set( 20, 20, 100 ).normalize();

                camera.add( dirLight );
                camera.add( dirLight.target );

                // texture

                var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
                manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                    console.log( item, loaded, total );

                };

                var texture = new THREE.Texture();

                var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
                loader.load( 'bigthumbnail.jpg', function ( image ) {

                    texture.image = image;
                    texture.needsUpdate = true;

                } );

                var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
                loader.load( 'Gamepad.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.position.y = 0;
                    scene.add( object );                

                } );
                // renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                controls.handleResize();

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                controls.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

                stats.update();

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have poured through the threejs.org website and looked at most of the examples. All of the examples that use complex colors use .bin files or .js files. So I downloaded Python 2.7.6, installed it and ran convert_obj_three.py. This generated a .js file, but I'm not sure it is correctly formatted. Unfortunately, The output that convert_obj_three.py gave me is too large to post. My Second question is which file format is best for complex coloring, like chrome blue? .bin, .js or can I use .obj? If using a .js is the best way to go then how can I reliably convert the .obj file to .js? By the way, I tried using the .js that was created by convert_obj_three.py, but the webpage is blank all the time. Seems I cannot load the .js using THREE.JSONLoader().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need to create a material and add it to your object?

Comment: @2pha: no the loader function does that for you.

Comment: it loads the texture, but I don't think it applies it to the object material

Answer (score 3):

after `loader.load` function is executed you get a threejs Object3D object. which contains the meshes of your object .

so you need to traverse over them to change the color of the material. The code will be something like this.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
                loader.load( 'Gamepad.obj', function ( object ) {

                   object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                             if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                                  child.material.ambient.setHex(0xFF0000);
                                  child.material.color.setHex(0x00FF00);
                                 }
                             } );

                    object.position.y = 0;
                    scene.add( object );                
            } );
```

Now the object's material has two properties which decides its color as you may see in the code `ambient` and `color` .

So this is to say that if in the scene you have white `AmbientLight` the object will appear Red(because the ambient property is set to #FF0000)

If the object is luminated by some other type of light like  `pointlight`  or `directionalLight` (as in your above case) the objects will appear Green(as `color` is set to #00FF00).

Now the last case if you have say that you have one white `AmbientLight` and one `DirectionalLight` in the Scene, then the object will appear as yellow as both `material.ambient` and `material.color` both will come into play and Red+Green will render as Yellow.
Hoping this helps.

Comment: No, no. Not `emissive`. You mean `color`, which is three.js's name for `diffuse`. `emissive` does not respond to lights.

Comment: @WestLangley: thanks for the response but I guess it does in some ways.

check this link http://metalop.com/test.html

Comment: @WestLangley: I have loaded an object and set its `ambient` color to `red`, `emissive` color to `green` and `color` to `blue`.

The source is illuminated just by a white  `DirectionalLight`,. and the object is being rendered as `green`.
I am just a very new user of Three.js so please correct/explain me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you a tutorial here. See http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter05.html.

Comment: @WestLangley: thanks mate, for the real good tutorial, it really helped.

Updated the answer. :)