# How to add color to some points on obj model using THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d-model

I want to let the user add color to some points of obj model by clicking on it.

I referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21326026/1127787) but it adds color on the whole model. I want to add on some points in the 3D context.

Comment: "Add color to some points" ... do you want to paint on the model? In that case, https://tomtung.github.io/chameleon.js/ is a nice three.js-based example.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Explain clearly what it is you are trying to achieve and maybe add some code of what you have already tried.

Comment: @Paul-Jan yes thats what i wanted..thanks!